# $\int_{y=-1}^{y=1}\int_{x=y^{2/3}}^{x=(2-y)^2}f(x,y)\ \mathrm dx \mathrm dy$ what does the region look like?

Tags: integration

More specifically, I have a double integral
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{y^{2/3}}^{(2-y)^2}f(x,y) \ \mathrm dx \mathrm dy$$

It is mostly the $y^{2/3}$ that is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I try to draw your region by sage. That's what it looks like.

The green graph is :$x=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$

The blue graph is :$x=(2-y)^2$

Code sage:

x = var('x')

p1 = parametric_plot(((x-2)^2,x),(x,-4,4),rgbcolor=hue(0.5))

p2 = parametric_plot(((x^2)^(1/3),x),(x,-4,4),rgbcolor=hue(0.4))

p3 = parametric_plot((x,-1),(x,-5,11),rgbcolor=hue(0.6))

show(p1+p2+p3)

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here the red curve is $x=(2-y)^2$, and the brown curve is $x=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$. The horizontal lines are $y= \pm 1$.

[image: The region]

I was hoping you might add some interesting function $z=f(x,y)$ so that I could show a solid in 3 dimensions.